# Average case complexity for checking if list is sorted

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

> Consider the obvious algorithm for checking whether a list of integers
>   is sorted: start at the beginning of the list, and scan along until we
>   first find a successive pair of elements that is out of order. In that
>   case, return false. If no such pair is found by the time we reach the
>   end of the list, return true.
>   Suppose that the input list is a random permutation of $1, 2, \ldots, N$
>   and all such permutations are equally likely. Derive the average-case
>   expected running time. Give both an exact and asymptotic answer.

The complexity for a given list depends on when the first pair of out-of-order elements are encountered. Let $c_N\left(n\right)=n$ be the complexity for a list where the $n$th pair is the first that is out-of-order.

Let $p_N\left(n\right)$ be the probability that the $n$th pair of the list is the first that is out-of-order.

Then I understand that the average case complexity is given by $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} p_N\left(n\right)c_N\left(n\right) + \left(1 - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} p_N\left(n\right)\right) \left(N-1\right)$.

However, I have been struggling to derive $p_N\left(n\right)$. By hand-working a number of examples, I have identified that $p_N\left(n\right) = \frac{1}{a\left(n\right)}$, where $a\left(n\right) = n! + \left(n-1\right)!$ is the sequence [A001048](http://oeis.org/A001048).

I have tried to reverse-engineer a derivation by recognising that $p_N\left(n\right) = \frac{f_N\left(n\right)}{N!}$, where $f_N\left(n\right)$ is the number of lists whose $n$th pair is the first that is out-of-order. Algebra shows that $f_N\left(n\right) = n \frac{N!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$ but unfortunately I cannot see how this term would be derived.

I would appreciate any hints. Thank you in advance for your help!

P.S. I have also discovered via WolframAlpha the interesting property that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_N\left(n\right)c_N\left(n\right) = e - 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $\binom{N}{n+1}$ ways to choose the first $n+1$ elements of the list. There are exactly $n$ ways to order these so that the only pair out of order is the last pair: we must pick one of the $n$ elements other than the largest, put it at the end, and precede it by the remaining $n$ elements in increasing (i.e., sorted) order. Finally, there are $(N-n-1)!$ ways to permute the remaining elements of the list. Thus,

$$f_N(n)=n\binom{N}{n+1}(N-n-1)!=\frac{nN!(N-n-1)!}{(n+1)!(N-n-1)!}=\frac{nN!}{(n+1)!}\;.$$

Comment: Thank you; that is very helpful! I wish I could have seen it myself, but I am glad to know that I was on the right track :)

Comment: @Arman: You were indeed. You’re welcome!